# Can anyone tell me what is the type of this language?

Tags: python

query  = 'GATTACA';! genome = 'TGATTACAGATTACC';! ! nummatches=0;! ! % At every possible offset! for offset=1:length(genome)-length(query)+1! !% Do all of the characters match?! !if (genome(offset:offset+length(query)-1) == query)! !! !disp(['Match at offset ', num2str(offset)])! !! !nummatches = nummatches+1;! !else! !! !%Uncomment to see every non-match! !! !%disp(['No match at offset ', num2str(offset)])! !end! end! ! disp(['Found ', num2str(nummatches),' matches of ', query, ' in genome of length ', num2str(length(genome))])! ! ! disp(['Expected number of occurrences: ', num2str((length(genome)-length(query)+1)/ (4^length(query)))])!

Comment: i guess it is matlab.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB amigo, the disp and '%' for comments and num2str function are all MATLAB tid bits.